# Python runtime access to module functions or dynamic function creation

Tags: python, dynamic

I am coding a command line python application, and I want to access a module function known at run time.

I have looked at dynamically creating the function at run time from the following : https://snipplr.com/view/17819/

But the approach no longer does not appear to be valid.

Here is some non-working code:

```
from domains import *


def execute(name, func, arg1, arg2):
    pass


def main():

    if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
        print("Detected Python 2.x, but code requires Python 3.x. Exiting")

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--doms", help="dom name", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--arg1", help="arg1 name", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-b", "--arg2", help="arg2 name", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    dom = args.doms
    if dom in vars():
        func = vars()[dom].fn1
        execute(dom, func, arg1, arg2)
    else:
        print("{} not implemented!\n".format(dom))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Originally the code will work if placed in the if__name__ == **main** scope. But will break once in the main() function scope.

Any pointer to a better (more pythonic) approach will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `vars()`. Explicitly create a mapping, that is, a `dict`, that maps strings to the function objects you want. Then your dictionary won't depend on the scope you call `vars`  (a bad approach to begin with). You could probably just use `globals()` here, but again, that is just a messy, bad approach. If all your functions are going to be in the `domains` module anyway, don't do `from domains import *` (a bad practice) and simply use `import domains; func = getattr(domains, dom).fn1`

Comment: Thanks Juanpa, I do like the direction of this approach.  I do however have additional constraints. First, domains is actually a package containing a variety of modules. If I can get the dict to map string to module that would go a long way.

Comment: sure you can do just that